# Performance issue when using pyodbc with Python 3 to access MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, python-3.x, pyodbc, freetds

I have a performance problem when accessing an MS SQL Server 2008 using Python 3.X and PyODBC (FreeTDS as ODBC driver).

When I run the script with Python 2.7 it retrieves about 30000 rows per second. When using Python 3 the speed is reduced to approximately 7000 rows per second.

I've also tried to query MySQL through ODBC with Python2 and Python3 and the speed is surprisingly about the same in both versions.

Did anyone experience the same problems? Could it be solved by changing some configuration files?

Here is the configuration:

```
#odbcinst.ini
[FreeTDS]
Driver         = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup          = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
FileUsage      = 1
CPTimeout      = 
CPReuse        = 
client charset = utf-8

#freetds.conf
[global]
tds version = 7.2
port = 1433
client charset = utf-8
```

The connection string looks like this:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={FreeTDS};SERVER=[OUR_SERVER];PORT=1433;UID=[USER];PWD=[PASSWORD];DATABASE=[DATABASE];TDS_VERSION=auto')
```

Some additional information:
I'm using an Ubuntu 12.04 server with freetds v0.91-1 and pyodbc v3.0.7.

Thank you very much for some hints or inspiration

Comment: How are you measuring rows per second?

Comment: I'm writing then to a local file. The formula is: [number of rows] / ([end timestamp of for-loop] - [start timestamp of for-loop]).
It's just an approximation that's why I didn't write exact numbers